# Using new wordpress functionailities without upgrading

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a big website on Wordpress 4.5.3, I don't want to upgrade to 4.6 to not break anything, but I would like to use this:

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_post_type/register_meta_boxes/

How can I do it? is there any way to manually add those classes without updating the whole Wordpress?

Comment: By the way, it is better to ask WordPress questions at http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend you to do a backup and try a full update, chances are that the update won't break your site unless you have changed any core files.

You could do a 'hand' update, download the 4.6.1 version and replace the files that contain the classes that you want to use. And test if it works as intended (not guaranteed if you're not doing the full update)

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if you have a staging server or not.

But in my case, in my live server, I have the following in *wp-config.php*

```
define('WP_AUTO_UPDATE_CORE', false);
```

And this prevents automatic updates to the live server.

In addition to my live server, I have a development server and a staging server, with the exact same settings as the live server.

So, to update, I update my development server manually, fix all the issues that may happen. Then I update my stating server, and ensure it works, then if everything is OK, I apply the changes to my live server.

My advice is not to branch out of WP releases and apply custom/selective classes and features. It may work now, but on the long run, this would cause tremendouse problems and it would be harder for you to maintain. Do it right from the get go and you will be happy.

I use [this plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/nostracon-wp-debug/) to help me in debuigging.